# Server 2008 R2 Print Server

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, print-server

I have a Server 2008 R2 Print server with windows 7 and xp clients. When I add print queue on server, it asks for printer driver. Which print driver should I install on server? Server 2008 version or Windows 7 version or Windows XP version?

Answer (score 3):

You should have the option to add more than 1 driver, i.e. you should install as many additional drivers as you need.

Comment: This is the truth, right here. You can install multiple drivers to a print server, for the same printer, for the sole purposes of auto-delivering the right driver for the platform. Install as many driver variations as is required to automate the provisioning of the device in your network.

Answer (score 3):

Use the driver that allows the printer server to talk to the printer (so most likely the Server 2008 R2 driver) then use the printer management console to add the 32 bit and or 64 bit drivers. That way all clients (xp, win 7 32/64bit) will be able to use the printer server.

I have migrated all my printer servers to 2008R2 now and it works great for our xp/vista/win7 environment with a mix of 32 and 64 bit.

Comment: The drivers for the clients can be added after you prepare the relevant driver for the printer.  It is obvious to me now, but only after scratching my head a while back on installing the right printer drivers for x86 clients on a x64 server.

Comment: Some printer don't have driver for server 2008. So what should I do?

Comment: Usually a Windows 7 driver will work just fine on 2008 R2.

Answer (score 1):

I've been installing the "Server 2008 R2" driver if available, or the Win7 driver, and they've been working fine for my XP and Win7 clients. I do make a point of installing both 32-bit and 64-bit versions though.

Answer (score 0):

Install the 2008 drive.  Look at the manufacturers website for the particular printer you are installing and they should recommend the correct driver.  Often it will be the universal these days or if its a special printer with added functionality you will see a special package/driver.  I have still seen some issues with the special drivers and being able to toggle on the 32 bit driver.  Trying to install the 32 bit 2008 driver will fail because your R2 box is 64 bit only as well.  Switching to the Universal for that brand (Ricoh, HP, etc) will then allow an easy toggling of a check box to include your 32 bit driver.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add both drivers x86 and x64 so when a PC connect it will download from your server the drivers that need (etc. XP will download the x86 drivers) a win 7 x64 will download x64 drivers.

Maybe in some cases you will have to install local to machines the drivers